# Which is faster? Update multiple rows in one single query OR foreach() of single queries

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a million records: (user balances)

Which would be best practice / optimal / faster?

Executing multiple single queries for each row:

```
foreach( $row as $id => $value ):
     update users set balance = $value where id = $id
endforeach;
```

OR

Running a multiple row query:

```
update users
set balance = 
    CASE 
    WHEN id = 1 THEN $value1
    WHEN id = 2 THEN $value2
    WHEN id = 3 THEN $value3
    ....
    WHEN id = 999998 THEN $value999998
    WHEN id = 999999 THEN $value999999
    WHEN id = 1000000 THEN $value1000000
    END
```

Also, would I need to put `ELSE balance` right before `END`?

Thank you!

Comment: i know an easy way to find out .. benchmark it

Comment: unlike those below i would be inclined to use the loop for  easier error checking, fault control, scalability, and maintenance. But I Don't have enough information for anything definitive.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you truly have a million rows your second alternative, as written, won't work. There are limits on the length of SQL statements.
2. The concept of an UPDATE query without a WHERE clause on a large table containing valuable data is, frankly, frightening. It *will* update every row, whether you intended that or not.
3. Do these balance updates really arrive in a batch of a million? If so, it might make sense to upload them into a temporary table with `id` and `value` columns, then use something like this to update the original table.

```
    UPDATE users
     JOIN temptable ON users.id = temptable.id
      SET users.balance = temptable.value
```

You can upload that temptable using LOAD DATA INFILE or some other fast method of getting the data into your MySql server. You can inspect it and make sure it's right before you overwrite a whole bunch of `balance` values in your `user` table.

If a whole lot of users get the same exact change to their balance, you can do some thing like this

```
 UPDATE users
    SET balance = balance + 0.10
  WHERE user_category = 'gets_a_dime_a_day'
```

or something like that. Obviously I don't know what your `WHERE` clause should contain.

Comment: Currently roughly 100k users. What happens is that we run a shared profit website that distributes an amount of money among all users. The pool to distribute currently is 10k. So 10k / 100k users, we have increase the balance of each user on a 0.10$ on a daily basis. Would the JOIN table approach would be best?

Comment: See my update. You can use `UPDATE` clauses to increment values in tables, not just replace them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe running a single query is faster as it eliminates connection time. However, you might have to do a benchmark to proof that.

Also, foreach-looping queries is considered a `BAD PRACTICE`

Comment: who says " foreach-looping queries is considered a BAD PRACTICE" ? nothing is bad-practice with out context

Comment: Hmmm.... sorry. I think I should mention about `BEST practice` instead of using `bad practice` :s Where in this case he can use a single statement, then he should...

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating millions of records then you probably don't want to do it all in one query (which would be faster) but would lock the table for a long time.  Probably best to use a hybrid approach and chunk your updates into smaller groups.

Comment: What about if table is InnoDB, would it lock only one row at the time?